# run a function on main activity from preferences

Tags: android, preferences

I need suggestion as to what is the best way to achieve this:
I want to be able to run a function which requires access to my *sqlite database* by clicking on an option inside my preferences. I have been able to create a *PreferenceFragment* that properly manages my preferences.

I have been trying to find a way to directly call a function in my main activity but did not find any simple solution.

Is it possible to do such thing without a need to access main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If main activity means the activity that is managing the fragment this is easy. You can get access to the activity managing a fragment by calling getActivity(). So lets say your main activity is called MyActivity, use the following code to call a function named myFunctionCall on it.

```
    MyActivity mainActivity = (MyActivity)getActivity();
    mainActivity.myFunctionCall();
```

Comment: Would this require me to execute the preferencefragment without using intent?

Comment: This should be inside the preferencefragment and it will not matter how the fragment was added to the activity. Maybe post the code you are using to launch the fragment.